# What happens when a galactic body gets bigger?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, particle-physics, black-holes, galaxies

In my simple non-quantum non-nuclear but enthusiasm-filled mind, I fascinate that as a galactic body become much more massive, it can reduce matter first down to its building blocks, then eventually to its creator (the forces or fields that excited them).

In the Sun, it's 99.99% plasma (charged particles -- ion, alpha, electron, nucleons, etc).

In small Neutron stars, only the nucleons (neutron, proton) survive. But with bigger Neutron stars, reports suggest that matter is reduced further to mix of nucleons and quarks (or even full quark?) state.

Following this pattern, is it then possible that the next more massive body in queue (stellar BHs and Intermediate BH like GW190521), exotic interactions can reduce fermions to bosons (or to its field)?  Then in supermassive Black Holes, all gauge bosons get merged? And finally, in stupendously large quasars like TON 618, no boson but only gravity survive?

Are these wrongfully, misconceived, oversimplified conceptualizations of what happen as a galactic object get bigger?

Comment: Possibly important: [Quark-gluon plasma](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark-Gluon-Plasma)

Comment: Google "no-hair theorem for black holes."

Answer (score 1):

They're definitely wrong, because what sets a black hole apart is not its mass, but its density. For example a primordial black hole (if it exists) might have a mass of a large mountain, yet it would still be a black hole.

On the other hand if you changed the question to "what happens when a galactic body gets denser" then the relation still falls apart, since the Sun is much less dense than the Earth (for example).

What governs the state of matter in astrophysical objects are other things (such as temperature & pressure) that have some correlation with mass, but are not the underlying cause.

Comment: Density doesn’t set a black hole apart either. Supermassive black holes can have average densities (mass divided by the volume of the interior of the event horizon as perceived from outside of the horizon) to be less than the density of water.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov “*the volume of the interior of the event horizon as perceived from outside of the horizon*” is zero for a black hole of any size: https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1734

Comment: @safesphere how so? Black holes have a surface area and hence a perceived volume